# Is the girl in the poster of Homeland an actress of the show?

Tags: posters, homeland, child-actors

In the poster of [*Homeland*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeland_(TV_series)) there is a little girl. I checked the list of cast to find her name. The only suitable actress was Morgan Saylor. But when I opened her article I found out she will turn 29 just days later. So she was 17 in 2011 when the series was first released. So she can't be the little girl in the poster.

[image]

Is that little girl an actress of the show? I can't think otherwise because her image is in the poster and it's so dramatic. If she is an actress of the show why isn't she credited? Or maybe she is the younger self of one of the older characters (But still she is an actress of the show in this case too).

Comment: That is not the poster. That's merely a screengrab from the opening titles of the show. Did you actually watch the show or are you just trying to create questions to gather points?

Comment: @BCdotWEB Since the show title is in the picture I thought that's the poster.

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR:

OP asks a series of questions:

> *Is the girl in the poster of Homeland an actress of the show?*

With regards to that specific image, no, she is not.

> *I can't think otherwise because her image is in the poster and it's so dramatic.*

That choice is down to the production team, who they farm the job out to, and with who has creative control. It might be in there but it might not be important at all.

> *If she is an actress of the show why isn't she credited?*

If they are not the main talent or not considered eligible for credit then they will not get any. See below for more.

> *Or maybe she is the younger self of one of the older characters (But still she is an actress of the show in this case too).*

See below, yes, some images are of the main actress when younger, probably supplied by members of the family. But is that her at the beginning? No.

So, for the rest of the sequence:

Some, though not all, are actually Claire.

While not specified, IMDB entry states:

> Some of the photographs that are interspersed over the course of the opening credits sequence are actual pictures of Claire Danes as a young girl.

Also:

American photographer, Lloyd Wolf, had a photo of his daughter that was used in the title sequence. She wears the lion mask:

> ONE KID, ONE KID
>
> Enlarged polaroid prints with text of a year in the life of my 9-year-old daughter Emma. Funded by an Arlington Commission for the Arts grant in 1993.
>
> The photo of my daughter in the lion mask was used in the opening sequence of the television show “Homeland.”

https://focusonthestory.org/events/one-shot-the-story-behind-emma-in-a-lion-mask/

Regarding crediting, not everyone gets credit. Its usually up to a producer to decide who gets credit and they may not have even been given a full credit list. Also there are guidelines for who is entitled to get credit and who is not. When someone isn't then the onus might be on them to chase to include a credit, which after the fact usually ends up as (uncredited) at best on a site like imdb.

Claire did not sought credit for an image of her used, such a thing might be in her contract; Emma Wolf, the child with the lion mask has no credit, and no one would have known it was her if it had not been for her father mentioning it (it had already been in use as part of his project more than a decade earlier). It is possible that the girl in the title was shot as something else (like stock) or was so far down the line she (and her legal guardians because of her age) might not even know, or care, to get credit (after all they would've been paid separately and have nothing thereon to do with the production).

Interestingly, photographer Lloyd Wolf had not ever seen the show, which demonstrates how far different sources from a production can be.

Interesting update on Claires picture usage:

**Claire Danes reveals Homeland stole her baby pics**

https://www.sheknows.com/entertainment/articles/1097889/claire-danes-talks-homelands-opening-credits/amp/

> “They really feel like they might mean something.”
>
> Well, according to Danes, the answer is that they mean absolutely nothing.
>
> Though she did have an interesting tidbit about those opening credit photos, revealing, “Some of those **photos of me as a little girl are actually me**. **I didn’t know they had those photos**, and then I saw the credits and I was like, ‘**Where’d they get that?**’ They’re **me with the little pin curls**.”

[image]

Personally, I've done jobs like this (a lot less interesting), and its often the producer or picture research that's come in with these, having cleared them with the family, but not necessarily with the artist themselves, so as Claire Danes found out, quite often they don't know until its aired.

Usually we do some hi res scans and they end up in the production assets library, after we've had our way with them.

*That said, and in my comment, there is something inherently 'stock' about the first girl (sleeping) in the title sequence. If you have been working in advertising, or some sort of creative endeavour for some time, you start to notice what might be stock and what might not be, and she looked stock. So technically, although she might well be an actress or model, she is not directly related to the show. She would have been hired by and shot directly for the production company (or individual) to create a piece of moving image that is then sent to a 'stock' catalogue that then licenses these pieces to others for a fee, taking some of the payment as commission and the rest to the production company that made it. The model would have been compensated separately by the production company, at the time of the shoot, perhaps a buyout fee (a larger one off payment as compensation, so no more payments would be due regardless of how and where the images are used later). Unless you knew (or of) the model/actress hired, or the people shooting her directly, you would never know her identity.*

TCG Studios did the title sequences and have had several interviews regarding the sequence.

And finally, I was correct about the first girl being stock:

> Some of the pictures from Carrie’s youth — the pigtailed **little girl seen sleeping** and watching Ronald Reagan on television — were **licensed stock** images. Others, including the photo of Carrie standing in front of a piano and as a teenager stuck in a maze, are **actual photos of star Claire Danes that were supplied to the TCG team**.

[image]

https://www.washingtonpost.com/entertainment/tv/dont-hit-fast-forward-opening-title-sequences-are-a-vital-part-of-tvs-best-shows/2014/04/04/97c8cd36-b8ee-11e3-96ae-f2c36d2b1245_story.html

http://www.tvworthwatching.com/post/Main-Titles-Up-Close-Homeland.aspx

https://www.tcgstudio.com/homeland_sequences

Comment: TBH, i'm not sure that specific shot is of her - seems like a stock image. The other picture that is of a slightly older, but still child-Carrie, is definitely Claire Danes of course.

Comment: The first Lloyd you have written is started with a small letter.